# How to disable menubutton in Polymer's core-scaffold?

Tags: dom, polymer

How to disable menubutton in Polymer's core-scaffold? And I want to disable drawer-panel in core-scaffold.

[image: core-scaffold with menubutton]

Answer (score 0):

Its embedded in **core-scaffold** as you can see from it's source code (**core-icon-button**):

```
  <core-toolbar>
    <template if="{{!rightDrawer}}">
      <core-icon-button id="menuButton" icon="menu" on-tap="{{togglePanel}}"></core-icon-button>
    </template>
    <content select="[tool]"></content>
    <template if="{{rightDrawer}}">
      <core-icon-button id="menuButton" icon="menu" on-tap="{{togglePanel}}"></core-icon-button>
    </template>
  </core-toolbar>
```

https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/blob/master/core-scaffold.html

You are better of building your scaffolding yourself using above url as a guide.

Also you might look into polymer 1.0 and [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) which will allow you change or remove the icon